# Setting RPATH of Static Library in Executable

Tags: cmake, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have the following setup for my CMake project:

```
add_executable(exeA ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(exeA PRIVATE libB)
```

`libB` is a *static* library built separately in a different project and depends on *shared* libraries `libC` OR `libD` which provide equivalent API's but implemented differently and have different performance profiles.

In `exeA`'s build I want to be able to link against either of `libC` or `libD` depending on a condition.

From reading [RPATH handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling#cmake-and-the-rpath), it seems I could use `RPATH` related CMake properties, however its unclear if I can use these properties to set the RPATH of an existing static library

> Unfortunately there is no easy and fast way to change the RPATH of an
> existing executable or shared library.

Is something like this possible to do in CMake?

Appreciate any recommendations to handle this use case.

Comment: Came across [patchelf](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf) which could do the task here by changing the RPATHs of `libB` based on a condition, but it feels a bit odd. A CMake only solution would be nice.

Comment: `on a condition.` use `dlopen`. `set the RPATH of an existing static library` that is unclear to me - who cares what object files in static library have. Set the RPATH on executable, only code is used from the object files.

Comment: Regarding the question title, static libraries don't have RPATHs.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `STATIC IMPORTED` library for `libB` and `SHARED IMPORTED` libraries for `libC` and `libD`. Put the relevant one in the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property of `libB`. CMake will set the RPATH correctly when `exeA` is built.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(test)

# --------------------------------------------------
# The following code should probably be factored out
# into a proper Find module.

find_library(LIBB_LIBRARY NAMES B REQUIRED)
find_library(LIBC_LIBRARY NAMES C REQUIRED)
find_library(LIBD_LIBRARY NAMES D REQUIRED)

add_library(third-party::libC SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
  third-party::libC
  PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LIBC_LIBRARY}"
)

add_library(third-party::libD SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
  third-party::libD
  PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LIBD_LIBRARY}"
)

add_library(third-party::libB STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
  third-party::libB
  PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LIBB_LIBRARY}"
)

option(LIBB_USES_LIBC "dummy option for demo" ON)
if (LIBB_USES_LIBC)
  target_link_libraries(third-party::libB INTERFACE third-party::libC)
else ()
  target_link_libraries(third-party::libB INTERFACE third-party::libD)
endif ()

# --------------------------------------------------

# --------------------------------------------------
# Project code

add_executable(exeA main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exeA PRIVATE third-party::libB)
```

You can test this out with dummy files like so:

```
$ ls
CMakeLists.txt
$ mkdir -p prefix{1,2}/lib
$ touch prefix1/lib/lib{C,D}.so prefix2/lib/libB.a main.cpp
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$PWD/prefix1;$PWD/prefix2"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build
$ cmake --build build -- -nv  # dry run (n), verbose (v)
[1/2] /usr/bin/c++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/exeA.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/exeA.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/exeA.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/alex/test/main.cpp
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/c++   CMakeFiles/exeA.dir/main.cpp.o -o exeA  -Wl,-rpath,/home/alex/test/prefix1/lib  ../prefix2/lib/libB.a  ../prefix1/lib/libC.so && :
```

As you can see, the `RPATH` is set correctly to the directory containing `libC.so`.